# Создание поддоменов в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, домен, поддомены

Стоит задача создать поддомены по городам РФ к основному домену. Хостинг на nic.ru, управление сайтом - WordPress. Для мультисайта создавались поддомены на хостинге под каждый город, например москва.сайт.ру. Затем в WordPress добавлялся сам сайт в режиме "Поддомен". Но создаются они абсолютно "чистыми", ввиду того что на хостинге папка у поддомена пустая, т.е. не подгружает корень папок основного домена сайт.ру.
Также пробовалось создание поддоменов только в WordPress, на хостинге не создавались - итог такой же: товаров нет, категорий нет, страниц нет, есть только плагины.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает как создавать поддомены для основного сайта в связке с WordPress. Возможно я что то делаю не так.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/ustanovka-multisite-mu

Comment: https://hostiq.ua/blog/wordpress-multisite/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Создание_сети

Comment: Да, делал по этим руководствам, но итог я описал выше.

Comment: Во первых смени хостинг на нормальный, а во вторых внимательно читай мануалы. Тебе либо НЕ НАДО вручную созодавать поддомены (настроить вилкард) либо создавать их алиасами к основному.

Comment: Какой хостинг считается нормальным? Вторая часть про поддомены не совсем понятна..

Comment: @Serj см отсюда https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%b8%d1%89%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8/#post-301217 и до половины след страницы.

Comment: По хостингу рекомендую Бегет или Таймвеб

Comment: @mihdan не ровняй свои  перс условия с ширпотребом. Тем более (по слухам) на бегете есть какие-то ограничения на поддомены/вилкард.

Comment: @SeVlad Любой хостинг, отличный от nic.ru будет лучше, в любом случае. С Таймвебом проблем не ощущал, кроме одной неприятной штуки - сайты не изолированы друг от друга на одном аккаунте. С Бегетом начал работать пару месяцев назад и впечатления только положительные.

Comment: @mihdan вот попробуй на ширпотребовском тарифе бегета поднять мультисайт.. По слухам (я-то его не юзаю) это или не возможно в принципе или такие ограничения, что нет никакого смысла. С таймебом сразу нет смысла - там дикие ограничения даже на обычный сайт (https://timeweb.com/ru/services/hosting/rules/), какой уж тут мультисайт...Даже на "мощных тарифах" у них рекомендуется не более 5к юзеров/день.

Comment: На таймвебе поднимали мультисайт - там с этим нет проблем, другой вопрос, что сам по себе мультисайт тяжел для любого шареда. Спасает полностраничный кэш.  На Бегете 100% можно поднять мультисайт в поддиректориях, на поддоменах возмжно нет - там же специально для безопасности сделали песочницу под каждый сайт. Я узнаю и отпишусь.

Comment: @mihdan тяжелый не "мультисайт", а КАК сделан сайт (любой) и какой на него траффик. Нормальный шеред за 500руб/мес у меня и 30к юзеров/день держит. А саппорт твоего любимого  таймвеба от такой цифры пришли в шок и сказали "однозначно ВПС" причем  даже не минимальный. У них ЛЮБОЙ, даже самый мощный тариф (битриксовские в тч)  до 5к юзеров.

Comment: Пообщался с поддержкой Таймвеба и Бегета и у обоех компаний есть возможность заводить мультисайты. Никаких ограничений в этом плане они не накладывают. Так что твои слухи не оправдались. @SeVlad

Comment: Любой сайт, сделанный на коленке рукожопым доширакером будет тормозить на любом тарифе, согласен. Но речь про то, что сама реализация мультисайт в WordPress реализована тяжеловато, мы смотрели через xdebug. Особенно когда подсайтов больше трёх. Я уже молчу, что безопасность мультисайта оставляет желать лучшего, но это мало относится к теме разговора. Так как мультисайт - одно ядро, то при взломе подсайта, пострадает вся сеть.